# c# uwp multiple active bluetooth connections

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently working on a program for work and I have been researching how to connect to multiple Bluetooth devices at once. This program runs on a Microsoft surface and will need to get all available and compatible Bluetooth devices and then keeps the connections because the devices send data over a serial port/Bluetooth converter. I am able to connect to one but I cannot figure out how to add an array of Bluetooth devices. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can add devices one by one, and for each device you will need to enter the pin code prompt by windows. If you want to connect to multiple devices using only one pin, or without pin, it is not possible to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am connecting to devices that do not need a pin, they are developed by my company. You have to have a certain bit of code to both read and write information from the device. I am wanting to take a group of those devices and send commands to them.

Comment: Then you can  try connecting to your devices using [codes from Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth) based on the which type of Bluetooth device you are using(RFCOMM or BLE)

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Thank you, that has helped.